# Android dateFormat.parse(date) I send 01/03/2021 it shows sun dec 27 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2020

Tags: java, android, date, calendar, addition

I am having a problem with this class where the string date is in format `MM/dd/YYYY`. The boolean is `true` to add a day and `false` to subtract a day.

Sending `01/03/2021` and on `c.setTime(dateFormat.parse(date));`, the value that it getting is `Sun "Dec 27 00:00:00 GMT-05:00 2020"`. I don't understand what is the problem.

```
public static String dateDay(String date,boolean add){
    SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    try {
        c.setTime(dateFormat.parse(date));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    if(add)
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,1);
    else
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR,-1);
    dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
    Date newDate=new Date(c.getTimeInMillis());
    String resultDate=dateFormat.format(newDate);
    return resultDate;
}
```

Comment: Which language is this written on? I can't tell.

Comment: As an aside consider throwing away the long outmoded and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` and friends. See if you either can use [desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) or add [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) to your Android project, in order to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API. It is so much nicer to work with.

Comment: @MarkGiraffe It’s Java (one of the more popular languages for Android development) (I have added the language tag).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SimpleDateFormat()` uses lowercase `yyyy` for year not uppercase.
Change the line

```
dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/YYYY");
```

to

```
dateFormat=new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
```